# What are good alternatives to UIPicker?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, drop-down-menu, uipicker

I am working on a basic ordering UIViewController using the AQGridView to display multiple columns of products so I can use as much space as possible. For the time being I implemented UITextFields to enter the quantities for each product.

I am trying to find an alternative to UIPicker, some sort of dropdown. The fact that both, the entering text directly to the UITextField and the UIPicker bring up either the keyboard in the case of the UITextField or simply occupies a big portion of the screen from the start for the UIPicker.

Does anyone know of any alternatives to use? Or if there is a way to have a tiny UIPicker just on the cell for each product?

I guess I can simply play around with the individual cell and add the UIPicker with given CGRect. The thing is that it will still occupy quite some space.

Answer (score 0):

Pickers are always the same size as the keyboard. Don't try to force a picker into a smaller space -- they look terrible when they're compressed, and that's like adding a note to the app store reviewers that says "Please reject my application."

Comment: Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: Remember that the user has to pick things with a fairly blunt instrument -- the end of his or her finger. Given that, making it easy to pick one item out of a group requires some real estate. For a small number of small items, UISegmentedController can work. For a larger group, you can display a table view modally, like a large picker. Popup menus are used for text editing commands (cut/copy/paste/undo), but that's not an element that you can use for other things. If you need something more compact, you may have to roll your own.